# jpos : getting error o.j.t.p.QueryHost.prepare:97 'mux.S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER' is not connected

Tags: jpos

No idea why am I getting this error : getting error

> o.j.t.p.QueryHost.prepare:97 'mux.S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER' is not
>   connected

my jpos server xml file is as below

```xml
    <server class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" logger="Q2" name="mpgs-server-7276" realm="mpgs-server-7276">
        <attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">7276</attr>
        <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.NACChannel"
                 packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager"
                 type="server"
                 logger="Q2"
                 header="6000000000"
        >
            <property name="packager-config"  value="cfg/packager/CISascii.xml" debug="True" />
            <property name="timeout" value="180000"/>
        </channel>
        <request-listener class="org.jpos.iso.IncomingListener" logger="Q2" realm="incoming-request-listener">
            <property name="queue"  value="S2M_E02_MPGSTXNMGR" />
            <property name="ctx.DESTINATION"  value="S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER" />
        </request-listener>
    </server>
```

my txn manager as below

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <txnmgr class="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager" logger="Q2">
        <property name="queue" value="S2M_E02_MPGSTXNMGR"/>
        <property name="sessions" value="2"/>
        <property name="max-sessions" value="128"/>
        <property name="debug" value="true"/>

        <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.QueryHost"/>
        <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.SendResponse"/>
    </txnmgr>
```

my mux as below

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER">
        <in>mpgsrsc-s2me02-receive</in>
        <out>mpgsrsc-s2me02-send</out>
        <ready>mpgs-S2M-E02-channel</ready>
    </mux>
```

my channel as below

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <channel-adaptor name='mpgs-S2M-E02-channel' class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
        <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.NACChannel"
                 packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager"
                 logger="Q2"
                 header="6000000000"
                 >
             <property name="packager-config"  value="cfg/packager/AS280501.xml" debug="True" />

            <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
            <property name="port" value="6269" />
            <property name="timeout" value="180000"/>
        </channel>
        <in>mpgsrsc-s2me02-send</in>
        <out>mpgsrsc-s2me02-receive</out>
        <reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
    </channel-adaptor>
```

I send the below transaction to channel

```xml
    <log realm="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager" at="2020-05-07T01:51:54.931" lifespan="12014ms">
      <abort>
        txnmgr-1:idle:1
        <context>
          TIMESTAMP: Thu May 07 01:51:42 AEST 2020
          SOURCE: org.jpos.iso.channel.NACChannel@277ca244
          REQUEST:
           <isomsg direction="incoming">
             <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[cfg/packager/CISascii.xml] -->
             <header>6000000000</header>
             <field id="0" value="0200"/>
             <field id="2" value="5000100100700010"/>
             <field id="3" value="000000"/>
             <field id="4" value="900000005000"/>
             <field id="7" value="0507015142"/>
             <field id="11" value="015142"/>
             <field id="12" value="015142"/>
             <field id="13" value="0507"/>
             <field id="14" value="2005"/>
             <field id="18" value="7399"/>
             <field id="22" value="812"/>
             <field id="25" value="15"/>
             <field id="32" value="599950"/>
             <field id="33" value="004601"/>
             <field id="37" value="070520015142"/>
             <field id="41" value="UTIS2I25"/>
             <field id="42" value="000000EUREKAAIR"/>
             <field id="48" value="543432303730313033323132343332386A48796E2B3759466931455541524541414141764E5565364876383D39323033313233363130353030303031" type="binary"/>
             <field id="49" value="356"/>
             <field id="61" value="1025100006600356"/>
             <field id="120" value="9049                                                 9252   AirTicketNo0123OrderInf001234567890123456789012349360                                                            940800000000"/>
           </isomsg>

          DESTINATION: S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER
          RESULT:
           <result>
             <fail>
               [HOST_UNREACHABLE] o.j.t.p.QueryHost.prepare:97 'mux.S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER' is not connected
             </fail>
           </result>
```

I can see 6269 port is connected on the server , but it is still complaining about HOST unreachable

```xml
    <log realm="channel/127.0.0.1:6269" at="2020-05-07T02:00:33.102">
      <connect>
        Try 0 127.0.0.1:6269
      </connect>
    </log>
```

much appreciate if you help to solve this issue or any guidance what should i be checking

thanks in advance

note : the question is full of code , but i don't have any choice more than that to explain what's happening in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your ready key wrong in your mux, the ready key exported by a channel adaptor is it's name with a `.ready` suffix appended.

```xml
    <mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="S2M-E02-MPGS-AUTORESPONDER">
        <in>mpgsrsc-s2me02-receive</in>
        <out>mpgsrsc-s2me02-send</out>
        <ready>mpgs-S2M-E02-channel.ready</ready>
    </mux>
```

As the ready is pointing to a key never updated by anyone, the mux always thinks the destination is not connected and its `isConnected` method rteturns `false`